# In Javascript, my onEvent isn't being called, while other onEvents are

Tags: javascript, blackjack

I'm currently creating a blackjack game. In my game, when the user clicks "Stay", the program is suppose to find who is closer to 21, the user or the house. When I click stay, nothing occurs in my program. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

```
onEvent("stayButton","clicked", function()   {

 if (userTotal == 21) {
      setText("userArea","Player total is: " + userTotal +" Player wins!");
 }
  houseTotal();

  while (houseTotal < 17)  {
    appendItem( houseHand,deck.pop() );
    houseHandTotal();
  }

  if (houseTotal > 21) {
   setText("houseArea","House busts, User wins");
   var userWins = betAmount * 1.2;
   TotalMoney = TotalMoney + userWins;
  }

  setText("houseArea",houseHand + "house total is: " + houseTotal);

  if ( 21 - userTotal < 21-houseTotal && userHandValue != "bust" && houseHandValue != "bust")   
  {
    setText("userArea","Player total is: " + userTotal +" Player wins!");
  }

  else if (21 - userTotal > 21-houseTotal && userHandValue != "bust" && houseHandValue != "bust") 
  {
    setText("userArea","Player total is: " + userTotal +" Player loses!");
  }

});
```

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the question editor and post properly indented code.

Comment: As well, post your HTML. And does your browser console show any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `onEvent` is a wrapper for `addEventListener`, then the proper event name is `click`, not `clicked`.

Other minor clean up points:

- Also, use `===` and `!==` for equality comparisons instead of `==` and `!=` to avoid type conversion related nuances.
- Lastly, mostly stylistic, JS code tends to prefer single quotes for strings `'`.
- Not JS specific, but try using a logical approach to new lines in your code to make it readable.

```
onEvent('stayButton', 'click', () => {
  if (userTotal === 21)
    setText('userArea', 'Player total is: ' + userTotal + ' Player wins!');

  houseTotal();
  while (houseTotal < 17) {
    appendItem(houseHand, deck.pop());
    houseHandTotal();
  }

  if (houseTotal > 21) {
    setText('houseArea', 'House busts, User wins');
    let userWins = betAmount * 1.2;
    TotalMoney = TotalMoney + userWins;
  }

  setText('houseArea', houseHand + 'house total is: ' + houseTotal);

  if (21 - userTotal < 21 - houseTotal && userHandValue !== 'bust' && houseHandValue !== 'bust')
    setText('userArea', 'Player total is: ' + userTotal + ' Player wins!');
  else if (21 - userTotal > 21 - houseTotal && userHandValue !== 'bust' && houseHandValue !== 'bust')
    setText('userArea', 'Player total is: ' + userTotal + ' Player loses!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It helped a lot